# Azure back up unable to delete backup items

Tags: azure, backup, azure-backup-vault

I used the Azure Backup client (MARS) to back up a server he had.  The server no longer exists. In the Azure portal I am unable to delete the vault because the resource group contains backup items.

I tried using Powershell but Az.RecoveryServices is not meant to be used for MARS BackupManagementType.  You can Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer but then Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem fails because there is no WorkLoadType for MARS

So I cant delete the backup items from the Portal.  I cant delete backup Items using powershell and the server no longer exists so I can use the MARS agent to delete items.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete a Recovery Services vault that has servers registered in it, or that holds backup data.

To gracefully delete a vault, unregister servers it contains, remove vault data, and then delete the vault.
If you try to delete a vault that still has dependencies, an error message is issued, and you will need to manually remove the vault dependencies, including:
Backed up items
Protected servers
Backup management servers (Azure Backup Server, DPM) 
Refer to this article for detailed info:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-delete-vault

Note: You can use Cloud Shell available in portal to achieve this. Please select PowerShell after you launch Cloud Shell.

Kindly let us know if the above helps or you need further assistance on this issue.

Comment: No. This doeesn't help. I have already gone thru the link you give above.  The important thing to note in my case is that the MARS that was used to make the backups NO LONGER EXISTS.

Comment: Trying to use Cloud Shell-PowerShell I get message that "You have no storage mounted" and it wants me to create an Azure file share.

Comment: Can you share me the screen shot of the error  message?

Comment: I can get you screen shots of whatever you want to see. What specifically would you like screen shots off?
1. Using Azure portal to attempt to delete backup items
2. Remove-AzureRmBackupVault - doesnt work because it is for VMs, not on premise physicals servers like in my case